# commandButton action method not invoked in Liferay

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

I've the below portlet `view.xhtml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

            <h:body>

                <h:form>
                    <h:commandButton value="TESTButton" action="#{navigationViewBean.submit}" />
                    <h:outputText value="TESTGetter: #{navigationViewBean.testField}" />
                </h:form>
            </h:body>
    </f:view>
```

And this managed bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "navigationViewBean")
@RequestScoped
public class NavigationViewBean {
    private String testField;
    public boolean lol = false;

    public void submit() {
        System.out.print("TEST BUTTON INVOKED");
    }

    public String getTestField() {
        System.out.print("TEST GETTER INVOKEDx");
        return testField;
    }

    public void setTestField(String testField) {
        this.testField = testField;
    }

}
```

The only thing I try to do, is to call a method which prints something to my console. The problem is that no matter what I do, the action method is never invoked. The getter method is properly called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about changing the global tag `<f:view>` by `<html>` ?

Comment: Not advisable to add <html> when you are in portlet world....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im not sure why, but after adding this line to my `liferay-portlet.xml` it fixed it.

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

And here the whole block:

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>Test1</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
</portlet>
```

Comment: Daniel, your answer is correct. In Liferay 6.2 the portal namespaces request parameters with the portlet namespace by default. However, mojarra and JSF component libraries were incompatible with that feature at the time, so you needed to specify `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>`.

Comment: Since those libraries have been updated to work with namespaced parameters, we (the Liferay Faces team) are currently in the process of updating and testing those libraries with `<requires-namespaced-parameters>true</requires-namespaced-parameters>` (which is the default) so that you won't need to specify that option in the future.

Comment: For more details click [here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/migrating-from-liferay-faces-3-1-to-liferay-faces-3-2-4-2), [here](https://www.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/liferay-requires-name-spaced-parameters), and [here](https://www.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-liferay-faces-3-x-2-x-ga5-released).